# What will it take to build a small bluetooth device?

Tags: microcontroller, components, wireless, embedded, bluetooth

I am new to this part of StackExchange. I am doing a project that requires me to keep track of Bluetooth devices. So I want to build a tiny Bluetooth device that can be attached to almost anything; something tiny but effective. What will it cost to build this kind of device? What is the smallest size obtainable and how effective will it be?

Look forward your opinions!

Thanks!

Comment: How small is tiny? What is your definition of "effective"?

Comment: Also what is "almost anything"? Do you need to put Bluetooth on a gnat, or an A380?

Comment: VTC. This is a broad shopping question 4 years old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [Atmel Bluetooth](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500252) extension kit, and plenty of projects on other sites that describe interfacing Bluetooth with an AVR. You can also find tutorials for interfacing the AVR with a MicroSD card, so you could log all your data there.

SMT AVR chips are tiny and cheap. If you want to sacrifice size and price for faster development time, there is an [Arduino Bluetooth module](http://arduino.cc/it/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth). Arduino is AVR based, so you can always cost/size reduce later down to your own custom design once you've got the bugs worked out.

Edit: Browsing Mouser, I found the [TI CC2540](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540), a [bluetooth system-on-a-chip with an 8051 core](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2540.pdf).

Comment: Beware that cc2540 is a Bluetooth low-energy SOC, i.e. is it incompatible with anything but Bluetooth 4.0 BLE.

Comment: Hi, @ObscureRobot, avakar: Do you think I can do this myself? I have no solid experience in building electronic stuff like that. Is there anything you could recommend me? It's also difficult to get hold of the component coz they sell it in bulk, so I'm a bit confused on how to deal with that. Thanks

Comment: I'd need to know more about your project, experience, timeframe, etc. to give you good advice. Since you don't have much solid electronics experience, I suggest you start out with an Arduino and a Bluetooth shield. That will result in a package a little bigger than an Altoids tin, but will use off-the-shelf components that basically snap together. You can then focus on coding up your software and verify that it works. After that, you can look into shrinking it down to a smaller package, possibly hiring a design engineer to do the hard work.

Answer (score 3):

What does the Bluetooth device have to do and how small should it be? Say the amount of physical space you have available!! It's easy to say "tiny but effective" but we have no idea what your interpretation of "tiny" is.

The smallest usable complete Bluetooth device I am aware of is the Roving Networks RN42, but this is probably getting close to a "shopping" question :-(

Comment: That module is pretty "big".  I don't see earpieces using a 0.52" x 1" x 0.07" modem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. By small/tiny, I mean the smallest size obtainable.. Was also looking for contributions on how to go about the project.